# Prove that $Re+Rf=Re\oplus R(f-fe)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

> Let $e,f$ be idempotent elements of a ring $R$. Prove that $Re+Rf=Re\oplus R(f-fe)$.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93259/question-about-characteristic-of-idempotent?rq=1) solves the first part of my question. How should we prove the second part, that $e,f$ are orthogonal?

Help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is a good idea to say what you have tried and how far you have come in your attempts. That way it is easir to provide a better answer.

That being said, here are some hints: You need to show two things. First, that $e$ and $f-fe$ spans $Re + Rf$, and secondly that $e$ and $f-fe$ are orthogonal.

For the first, notice that we certainly have a containment $\supseteq$. The opposite inclusion is also straight-forward.

Secondly, what happens if you multiply $e \cdot (f-fe)$?

Comment: What does "$e$ and $f-fe$ are orthogonal" mean?

Comment: @user110834: Only that they multiply to zero.

Comment: $e(f-fe)=ef-efe=ef(1-e)$ What should I do then?

Comment: It's $(f-fe)e=0$.